# LINQ to entities query (1 to many)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to build a query to the entities to get records including:

- `AssetWeapon`,
- `PersonOut`
- number of records with `IsIn = True`,
- number of records with `IsIn = False`,
- name of the month of `StartTime`,

Records should be grouped by `AssetWeapon`

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4fee01b48c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4fee01b48c.png)

Comment: I just don't know how to build a query. my stupid mind isn't working properly to get this done ;)

Comment: Ok I got to this point and stuck...

var query = from ta in db.Transactions_Assets.Include("Transaction")
                            select new
                            {
                                Weapon = ta.AssetWeapon,
                                Month = ta.Transaction.StartTime.Value.Month,
                                In = ta.IsIn ? 1 : 0,
                                Out = ta.IsIn ? 0 : 1
                            };

Answer (score 0):

here what I've got finally:

```
var query = from ta in db.Transactions_Assets.Include("Transaction")
                        let items = new
                        {
                            Weapon = ta.AssetWeapon,
                            Month = ta.Transaction.StartTime.Value.Month,
                            IsIn = ta.IsIn 
                        }
                        group items by items.Weapon into g
                        select new { 
                            Weapon = g.Key,
                            MonthlyFlow = from m in g 
                                    group m by m.Month into mg
                                    select new { Month = mg.Key, 
                                                 Ins = mg.Count( x => x.IsIn == true),
                                                 outs = mg.Count(x => x.IsIn == false)
                                    }
                        };
```